# Opencv VideoWriter: how to get an output video with the same "rate" as a live inference of the model?

Tags: python, opencv, video, yolo

Here is a code to see "live" the inference of a YOLO model on a mp4 video:

```
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

video_path = "path/to/your/video/file.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

while cap.isOpened():
    success, frame = cap.read()
    if success:
        results = model(frame)
        annotated_frame = results[0].plot()
        cv2.imshow("YOLOv8 Inference", annotated_frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run this above code, it opens VLC and displays the video with boxes etc. and, since the model takes time to make the predictions, it's pretty laggy.

I would like to have this result (the laggy video) but **recorded**.

Problem is that if I do this:

```
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

video_path = "path/to/your/video/file.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

frame_num = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter('video_opencv.mp4',fourcc,30,(frame_width,frame_height))

while cap.isOpened():
    success, frame = cap.read()
    if success:
        results = model(frame)
        annotated_frame = results[0].plot()
        #cv2.imshow("YOLOv8 Inference", annotated_frame)
        video_writer.write(annotated_frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

which is basically the same but where I record the video instead of simply showing it, then when I read the video, it goes as fast as the original video (without predictions)

I hope I am clear.

Any solution for this ?

Comment: It is not possible in opencv to set a timestamp per frame. You have to choose a static fps for the video. Either you can estimate your detector fps or you choose a higher video fps and fill the lagged out frames with duplicates of the previous frame.

Comment: or use PyAV. it's the only wrapper around ffmpeg that can do this (to my knowledge)